# Plotly Dash: How to clear current graph plot before updating from dropdown values

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to update my candlestick chart in dash using a drop-down menu callback and everything [loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OYx4.png) fine.

But when I change the drop-down values the existing plots doesn't clear, instead graph is [plotted one on top of another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xtfi.png) including the plot of the previous selection.

How do I clear the current plot before updating plot values. Please help me resolve this issue.

This is my code

```
from enum import unique
import sqlite3
import os
from dash.dependencies import Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


folder = os.path.normpath("/Users/Name/Desktop/Desktop – Name’s MacBook Air/NSE/Nse Parser/")
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(folder,'Nse_data.db'))
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM eod_data ORDER BY Date""", conn)
all_stocks = df['SECURITY']

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div( style={'Color': 'grey',},

                children= [ 
                    html.Div([dcc.Dropdown( id='stock-selector',
                                    options= [{'label':x, 'value':x } for x in all_stocks], 
                                    value= "Nifty 50", clearable= False, searchable= True),],
                                    style={'width': 275,'marginTop': 30, 'marginLeft':250},),

                    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id= 'candlestick_chart')], 
                                style={'display': 'inline-block', 'float': 'left', 'marginTop':0})
                ]                 
                )

@app.callback(
    Output('candlestick_chart', 'figure'),
    Input('stock-selector', 'value'))

def candlestick(drop_value):
    dff = df.where(df['SECURITY']== drop_value)
    print(dff['SECURITY'])

    dff.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(dff['Date'])
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, 
               vertical_spacing=0, subplot_titles=('', 'Volume'), 
               row_width=[0.2, 0.7])

    fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x= dff['Date'],
                            open= dff['OPEN_PRICE'],
                            high= dff['HIGH_PRICE'],
                            low = dff['LOW_PRICE'],
                            close= dff['CLOSE_PRICE'], showlegend= False, 
                                        hoverlabel= {'split': True}), row= 1, col= 1)

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x= dff['Date'], y= dff['NET_TRDQTY'], showlegend= False), row= 2, col= 1)

    fig.update(layout_xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
    fig.update_layout(autosize= False, width= 750, height= 600, plot_bgcolor='white', 
                        hovermode= 'x unified', hoverdistance= 1000)
    fig.update_xaxes(showline= False, showgrid= False, type= 'category', visible= False, 
                        spikedash= 'solid', spikethickness= 1, spikesnap= 'cursor')
    fig.update_yaxes(showline= False, showgrid= False, spikedash= 'solid', spikethickness= 1, 
                        spikesnap= 'cursor')

    return fig

app.run_server(debug= True)
```

Comment: Hmm, weird. That doesn't happen normally when you update a graph using callbacks.
Try adding a `fig = go.Figure()` line [empty figure] before `make_subplots`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @Samarth. I tried your suggestion it doesn't work. I also tried 'fig.data =[]' after 'make_subplots' and still doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with my browser, I'm using firefox.

Comment: Try opening localhost in chrome or edge, see if it's different. (Don't think that's the case though)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a browser issue.

Comment: Can you provide the 'skeleton' of the dataframe?

Comment: '"""CREATE TABLE eod_data ([MKT] TEXT, [SECURITY] TEXT, [PREV_CL_PR] REAL, [OPEN_PRICE] REAL, [HIGH_PRICE] REAL, [LOW_PRICE] REAL, [CLOSE_PRICE] REAL, [NET_TRDVAL] REAL, [NET_TRDQTY] NUM, [IND_SEC] TEXT, [CORP_IND] TEXT, [TRADES] NUM, [HI_52_WK] REAL, [LO_52_WK] REAL, [Date] timestamp)""")' This is how I create the master table

Comment: I've noticed dash/plotly seeming a little buggy sometimes too. My advice would be to move all of the plot code to a separate function. e.g. `def make_cstick_plot(df, drop_value):`. Test the function all by itself in a notebook. If it's working fine, then transfer the function to the app and make the function call inside your callback. When I develop large dash apps, I always write plotting functions separate from callbacks for developing/testing/debugging.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the advise. I did something similar but brought in the 'read_sql'  within the callback function limiting the data available to plot and this worked.